# Show/Hide nested fields on newly added fields

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, cocoon-gem

This is a follow up question to the following question, mainly since I tried using some of the solutions on it and couldn't figure my way out:

[Change only the image inside same div when option from dropdown is chosen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25301314/change-only-the-image-inside-same-div-when-option-from-dropdown-is-chosen)

Given a form that has many questions, and you can optionally set the question to be multiple choice and add answers to it, I have the following view for questions(the field_answers method just renders the partial):

```
.nested-fields
  = f.input :question
  = f.input :type
  #answers{:style => "display:none;"}
    = f.simple_fields_for :answers do |m|
      = field_answers(m)
    %div{:class => "#links"}
      = link_to_add_association '+', f, :answers, :partial => 'layouts/form/answers', :class => 'link-add-field'
  = link_to_remove_association "remove question", f
```

And the following for answers:

```
.fields.answers-nested-fields
  #answer-field
    = f.input :answer
    = link_to_remove_association "-", f, { wrapper_class: 'answer-nested-fields',  :class => 'link-add-field remove_nested_fields' }
```

My questions.js.coffee has the following callbacks:

```
$('#type').change ->
  if $(this).val() is "text"
    $("#answers").hide()
  else
    $("#answers").show()

$(document).ready ->
  $('#questions').on("cocoon:before-insert", (e, question_to_be_added) ->
    question_to_be_added.fadeIn "slow"
  ).on("cocoon:after-insert", (e, added_question) ->
    added_question.css "background", "red"
  ).on "cocoon:before-remove", (e, question) ->
    # allow some time for the animation to complete
    $(this).data "remove-timeout", 5000
    question.fadeOut "slow"
```

The first bit is what works to make the answers to the first questions show or hide, clearly it does not work with newly added questions, for that I guess I'd need the before/after-insert callbacks to create an event where the show/hide on the answers field is fired when the question type is changed to anything other than "text", so how do I observe the change event on the type attribute of question?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a solution, it was really a jQuery problem and I just had to use .find()

```
$(document).ready ->
  $('#questions')
  ).on("cocoon:after-insert", (e, added_question) ->
    added_question.find('#type').change ->
      if $(this).val() is "text"
        added_question.find("#answers").hide()
      else
        added_pergunta.find("#answers").show()
  )
```